# How To Center Thumbnails Of jQuery LightGallery With In Dynamic CSS Website

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, thumbnails, center

Hey I was wondering if you can help me quickly. I have completely implemented everything and just having a slight issue with the centering of my ul coding. I have tried what is stated here and it’s not working. I've done it with the base coding, the HTML, with CSS, etc. And nothing so this is my coding and any advice would be really really truly greatly appreciated. (Can you tell I’m stressed for my client?)

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h2><center><img src="img/hdr-horsd.jpg"  style="width: 50%"></center></h2><br><br>
    </header>
    <ul id="light-gallery" class="gallery">
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-01.jpg">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-01.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-02.jpg" >
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-02.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-03.jpg">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-03.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-04.jpg" >
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-04.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-05.jpg" >
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-05.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-06.jpg" >
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-06.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-07.jpg" >
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-07.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-08.jpg" >
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-08.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-src="gallery/horsd-09.jpg" >
            <a href="#">
            <img src="gallery/t-horsd-09.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And then the custom CSS on the page is as follows:

```
    <!-- == Custom CSS Coding == -->
    <style>
        ul{
            list-style: none outside none;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        .gallery li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    width: 100px;
}
        .gallery li a {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .gallery li a img {
            max-width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
```

I know now it doesn't have any centering code in there, but that"s because I have removed it for it wasn't working and wanted to keep the code clean. The photo gallery I'm using that i want the thumbs to be centered for is called jQuery lightGallery

Answer (score 3):

Hi this may be a little late, but I had the same exact question and figured it out using Chrome Dev Tools. In your custom.css file, add:

```
#lg-gallery .thumb-cont .thumb-inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.lg-thumb.group {
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

this worker me in the latest release...

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<body>
<header>
    <h2><center><img src="img/hdr-horsd.jpg"  style="width: 50%"></center></h2><br><br>
</header>
    <div id="wrap">
        <ul id="light-gallery" class="gallery">
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-01.jpg">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-01.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-02.jpg" >
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-02.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-03.jpg">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-03.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-04.jpg" >
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-04.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-05.jpg" >
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-05.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-06.jpg" >
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-06.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-07.jpg" >
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-07.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-08.jpg" >
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-08.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-src="gallery/horsd-09.jpg" >
                <a href="#">
                <img src="gallery/t-horsd-09.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
   #wrap{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    width:1100px;
    height: 106px;
    text-align: center;
    }

   ul.gallery{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .gallery li {
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 100px;
    }

    .gallery li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    }

    .gallery li a {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .gallery li a img {
        max-width: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work :(. Does the CSS go into the gallery's CSS file or the style CSS file for the whole dynamic site? I'm wondering since it didn't work, it stays aligned to the left and the thumbnails do not center.. If you'd like i can link you to the page that isn't as of now connected to the site but rather just linking you to the HTML specific link on the server. Let me know if you need that or is the coding enough for you to figure it out. Either way i can give you both if you'd like just let me know what's easier for you and what your preferred preference is.

Comment: Ok, wait for a moment: it works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/bdLykuqq/embedded/result/ (I changed images src urls to let you see). I removed " width:1100px;" (now is even responsive). All code here: https://jsfiddle.net/npzg8euj/2/ .  I think it's ok if you put your css where it's logic for it to stay and it's important that it's well linked in your html page. Try to see, I'm here  :) (ps. sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I made a [temp page with the gallery on it](http://broadwaycaterers.ca/test.html) so you can actually see what I'm trying to do. I am wondering how to center the thumbnails you see there and also center the thumbnails on the actual gallery which you've done already but not sure how yo implement both of them to be centered within this one chunk of code. Just click on any thumbnail triggering the photo gallery to popup. I wanted the thumbs to be centered where ever the thumbs are displayed, wether it be on the page or below the gallery. If you can help me with that and tell me specifically where

Comment: First of all your English is great so don't worry :). Secondly, you should have a long life for taking the time in responding to my issues I'm stuck on in the development of this site and helping me to resolve this, I really appreciate it and have endless appreciation for you my brother or sister!?! :) You should have a long successful prosperous life.

So Basically the thing is like this, I made a temp page with the gallery on it so you can actually see what I'm trying to do. The link is as follows....

[link](http://broadwaycaterers.ca/test.html)

Continued.....

Comment: I am basically wondering how to center the thumbnails you see there and also center the thumbnails on the actual gallery which you've done already but not sure how yo implement both of them to be centered within this one chunk of code. You can see what I mean if you just click on any thumbnail triggering the photo gallery to popup. So, basically I wanted the thumbs to be centered where ever the thumbs are displayed, weather it be on the page pr below the gallery. If you can help me with that and tell me specifically where to put the jscripts and/or the css coding,

Continued...

Comment: meaning do they go dynamic either in the lightgallery.js or .css, in the general style.css or just on the specific page within the header of the page that I'm plugging the gallery into?! Thank you seahorse. You are a boss man and much respect. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Hey Everyone, Is there anyone here that can help me out? I've been stuck for a while and usually the response is super quick is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

For the version 1.3.5 inside your html document use

`<style>
    ul.lSPager.lSGallery
    {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    </style>`

That worked for me